# Java side validation (xwork2) does not work from input error page (Struts2)

Tags: java, validation, struts2, xwork

I am using Struts2 with jsp pages and xwork validation. My problem is in java side validation, when I first land in input-page due to input errors and after that I leave those errors there and submit again. The very same errors should be shown but they aren't. Java file contains field errors and those are not shown anymore after second try.

What is the problem? Missing interceptor or bug in struts2? I have the following interceptors:
- com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor
- com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor
- com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrametersInterceptor

I read from another thread that input landing page does omit the validation somehow. How can I enable the validation also when making calls from that page?

Comment: Why not post your action code? Something is wrong with your validate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need the `DefaultWorkflowInterceptor`, which is responsible for detecting validation errors and re-showing the form.

For any additional troubleshooting, you will need to provide your action code so that we can see what's up.